# .htaccess rewrite for removing 2 url segments

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have these URLs that need to be 'rewritten' using `.htaccess`... The first and last segment need to be removed, so

`/articles/marketing-stuff/seo-management/1418/` should

become `/marketing-stuff/seo-management/`

---

`/articles/command-line/linux-post/2131/` needs to

become `/command-line/linux-post/`

---

I have these rewrite rules but they're not working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /articles/marketing-stuff/(.*)/(\d+)/?
RewriteRule ^/articles/marketing-stuff/(.*)/(\d+)/?$ /marketing-stuff/$1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /articles/command-line/(.*)/(\d+)/?
RewriteRule ^/articles/command-line/(.*)/(\d+)/?$ /command-line/$1/
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^articles/(marketing-stuff|command-line)/(.*)/(\d+)/?$ /$1/$2/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is not working, the initial url is not changing, showing old page. I tested if my .htaccess file is being used and it is

Comment: If you try to change the url, it's not a rewrite, but a redirection. use `[NC,R=301]` instead of `[NC,L]`